# Do I have enough power for SLI, and current bottleneck in system?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

My current build consists of:

ASRock Z77 Extreme4-m
i5 3570k (planning to overclock to 4.2GHz)
GSkill RipjawX 1333MHz (F3-10666CL9D-16GBXL) (planning to OC, but need to read up on RAM OC first)
Gainward GTX460 GS 2GB x 2 (2gb memory per card)
Bitfenix Sceptre 120mm LED fans x 4
Coolermaster tx3 evo (planning water cooling soonish)
Corsair TX750 psu
Plextor 128gb SSD
Seagate Momentus XT 500GB

Is the current power supply good enough? Also, what should I be looking at upgrading first if it could be a possible bottleneck in the current system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your power supply is sufficient, but is fair. Two hard drives, two graphics cards (powerful like that) in parallel running at once, and that much RAM If you do not change now, the have to change later (soon) if that is what you plan to do. The setting is fantastic, but the power supply is just as you say and could create bottlenecks. A power 1000W should be enough.

Something like this:

http://www.hardocp.com/article/2012/11/13/seasonic_x1250_1250w_power_supply_review/#.UdwH5D4W5-U

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817341046 <-- SLI ready

http://ocz.com/consumer/psu/fatality-1000w-power-supply <-- SLI ready

http://www.corsair.com/professional-series-hx1000-80-plus-certified-modular-power-supply.html

Anyway, it depends on the budget you have.

In conclusion, as you now have your PC settings, not all the performance and sucrase surely create bottlenecks and the source will "forced". If you can, buy one of at least 1000W. It is also an investment for the future.

Comment: His graphic cards are average so 750W, provided the power supply is of average quality, should be more then enough.

Comment: I know they're old cards (got them for free :D) but I've also read they suck a lot of power (more than the 'standard' GTX460 1gb). But thnx for your answers.